# Bootstrap Modal is not working on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem, when I try to open a Bootstrap Modal-Pop-Up in Sharepoint 2013. When I test the Page local (Not using the Sharepoint masterpage") it works fine, but ,if I try to open the same Page in Sharepoint, the modal is not detected as a modal , so that the whole screen gets grey.

I hope someone can help me , Thanks a lot!

This is my Code:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#mymodal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></button>
<div id="mymodal" class="fade modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeader"></asp:Label></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Test</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was using the bootstrap3-custom.css of 
"Bootstrap 3 for SharePoint 2013 - Beta V1.0.2" and the following style caused the problem:

```
   #MainRow > div {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but you MUST change #MainRow > div {z-index: auto;}